# How much do egg yolks and whites weigh, in grams?

Tags: baking, eggs, egg-whites

I have an Italian recipe that has been translated to English. The recipe calls for 360g egg whites and 240g yolks. Can anyone tell me how much this is?

Answer (score 28):

The rule of thumb to divide an egg is:

- 60% egg-white
- 30% yolk
- 10% shell

So it depends on the size of egg you use (note that the [size definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_egg_sizes) varies between countries).

Example:
For a 60g (middle of the weight range) European M / American L egg, that's 60*0.6 = 36g whites and 18g yolk.

-> So you'd need (about) 10-11 whites and 13-14 yolks.

Of course, not all eggs have the exact same weight and therefore I recommend you *use the estimated number of necessary eggs as a guideline* and weigh the whites and yolks.

Comment: I raised birds and held an egg handlers license so will back up the guideline statement. If the recipe is delicate enough to be giving egg quantities in weights rather than egg counts, then I would definitely separate and weigh. Eggs will vary substantially, for instance shells will be thinner or thinker time of year and age/health/diet of bird that laid it. In US weight requirement for eggs are by the dozen even though listed as individual egg, so can vary in size within the dozen. Should you use non-chicken, the ratios change. Duck eggs for instance are a higher percentage yolk.

Answer (score 10):

Your best be would be to get a small kitchen scale.

**In general**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_egg_sizes

1/3 Yolk
2/3 White

So, for a Medium egg (49.6g), if my maths do not suck this morning.

White = 2/3 * 49.6g = 33g
Yolk = 1/3 * 49.6g = 16.5g

For 360g of white :  360g / 33g = 11 medium eggs
For 240g of yolk : 240g / 16.4g = 14.5 medium eggs

Comment: You are ignoring the shell....

Comment: remove the shell and recompute. (thus using a scale makes thing easier)

Comment: @Max It's nice to know the answer before you have to break any eggs though!

Comment: Canonically speaking, this is the answer.... get a scale, tare and weigh the egg fluids.

However, I doubt the OP's recipe requires "gram" precision. Probably, *medium* eggs would suffice for his/her application.

Comment: Nominally 15 eggs open one up and weigh is an excellent answer. Maybe open 3 and use 3 whites and 2 yokes would give you a better average.

Comment: @Paulb recipes from a professional context typically give eggs by weight, not number.

Answer (score 0):

Average accepted weight for a large egg in Canada, (w.o shell) is 50g, 30g white and 20g yolk.
For 360g of white, that would be 12 eggs. For 240g of yolks, also 12 eggs. 
You got lucky! Just seperate 12 eggs. 
If recipe calls for the gram, try to respect that as it is important, but you could get away with just separating 12 eggs. Happy baking!