# Weight of a large egg

Tags: baking

UK recipes give the  amount of eggs in a recipe in grams and I would like to know how many eggs I will need fpr 115 grams of eggs. So, what does the average large egg weigh?

Comment: Most UK recipes give a number of eggs, with a size (sometimes the size is in the introduction of a book). If stating grams they need to be clear about whether the shell is on or off at the time of weighing. Can you link to the recipe, or upload it? It's possible they want to be unusually precise, as that's a little less than two (UK)  large eggs, but two medium eggs might not add up to that much. Or they could have (un)helpfully converted

Comment: https://www.egginfo.co.uk/egg-facts-and-figures/industry-information/egg-sizes Which of course is of no use whatsoever if you're not also in the UK.

Comment: I've never seen a UK recipe give the amount of eggs in grams, I'm guessing this is rare.

Comment: @GdD some professional recipes do. We had a question about that, see [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77802/how-much-do-egg-yolks-and-whites-weigh-in-grams)

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a standard for egg sizes. Size M in Europe, corresponding to Large in the US, is roughly 55 grams per egg. This is including the shell, if you have a recipe which doesn't include the shell (e.g. it was developed for pasteurized eggs from a carton), you have to calculate about 5 g of shell for that size of egg.

You can look up tables of other egg sizes on the Internet, but that's the most common size in supermarkets, and the one most commonly used when developing recipes, so I suppose it is the one you need.